# WO2 Identity Server - ERROR: duplicate key value in the session cache

Tags: session, wso2, wso2-identity-server

having WSO2 IS 5.0.0.SP1 no HA deployment with PostgreSQL we occasionally have following exception in the log (and I believe the users are unable to log in, they need to close the application (web/mobile) and try again):

wso2carbon.log

`Error while storing session data {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.store.SessionDataStore}
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idn_auth_session_store_pkey"
  Detail: Key (session_id, session_type)=(315f9b01-6008-4794-b7d8-a76c7cc83102, SAMLSSOParticipantCache) already exists.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:562)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:420)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:366)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.store.SessionDataStore.persistSessionData(SessionDataStore.java:363)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.store.SessionDataPersistTask.run(SessionDataPersistTask.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)`

Session persistence configuration in the identity.xml:

```
        &lt;SessionDataPersist&gt;
                &lt;Enable&gt;true&lt;/Enable&gt;
                &lt;RememberMePeriod&gt;780&lt;/RememberMePeriod&gt;
                &lt;CleanUp&gt;
                        &lt;Enable&gt;true&lt;/Enable&gt;
                        &lt;Period&gt;60&lt;/Period&gt;
                        &lt;TimeOut&gt;781&lt;/TimeOut&gt;
                &lt;/CleanUp&gt;
                &lt;Temporary&gt;true&lt;/Temporary&gt;
        &lt;/SessionDataPersist&gt;
```

Any idea / hint would be appreciated.. Couldn't it be using the "back" button? When the session is persisted in the cache?

Thank you all in advance

Gabriel

Comment: There has been several enhancements in IS 5.1.0. Can you use it and try whether you getting this?

Comment: Hard to say - the client has multiple custom modules (authenticators) which won't work well in IS 5.1.0 :/ But - thank you for the tip, apparently there are many fixes and enhancements in the IS 5.1.0, in long term they'll need to migrate..